# How to properly fetch data from several API calls and display it to the DOM in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that displays the top results from a specific API call. My issue is how to properly and efficiently make several API calls and display them. I'm currently starting with two calls for the top TV and top airing.

I realize my initial state only holds one empty array and I need an extra for each specific result I want to return, but I'm currently stuck. I've attempted using async await to get one result, but I've been unsuccessful when calling more than one.

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    topTv: []
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const api = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3'
    const urls = [
      fetch(`${api}/top/anime/1/tv`),
      fetch(`${api}/top/anime/1/airing`)
    ]

    Promise.all(urls)
      .then(res => Promise.all(res.map(r => r.json())))
      .then(data => this.setState = ({
        topTv: data
      }))
      .catch(err => console.log('There was an error:' + err))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <HomeWrapper>
        <h2>Top anime</h2>
        <TopAnime>
          {this.state.topTv.map((ani) => {
            return (
              <div key={ani.mal_id}>
                <img src={ani.image_url} alt='anime poster' />
                <h3>{ani.title}</h3>
              </div>
            )
          }).splice(0, 6)}
        </TopAnime>
      </HomeWrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you have a `.splice(0, 6)` ?

Comment: It's to get the first 6 results from the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with current attempt is just the way you are using `setState`. 
It's a function and not a variable that you are setting.

```
this.setState = ({
    topTv: data
}))
```

It should be

```
this.setState({
    topTv: data
}))
```

Further you might want to merge the actual array from data and then setState.

```
 const results = [...data[0].top, ...data[1].top];
 this.setState({
    topTv: results
 }))
```

Note that `Promise.all` works just fine. However, if you're looking for ***async await*** example, I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qjn1wplql).

Do look that `urls` are just array of strings and not wrapped with fetch.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I was writing setState as a variable. I did go with the Async example.

Comment: working on this further. How would I display both arrays of data to the DOM? the first appears, but adding a second state doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace fetch with asyncawait fetchJson function that you created as below.

```
async function fetchJson(url){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    try{
        var resp = await fetch(url)
        data = await resp.json();
        resolve(data);
    }catch(e){
        //reject or do something else with the error
    }
}) }
```

And you can use it to fetch multiple calls as below.

```
const urls = [
fetch(`${api}/top/anime/1/tv`),
fetch(`${api}/top/anime/1/airing`)]

Promise.all(urls).then(responseArr=>{
    //do something with the array
}).catch(err=>{/*do something with error*/})
```

I think its much easier to write a function which handles nested callbacks or promise chain for me, so I wont need to bother with it everytime. Also there is no performance difference or waterfall effect this way.

Coming to specifying each calls, you would want to use a url array like

```
[{url:'myApiUrl', functionOrKey: ''}]
```

Then you can map the responseArr with index value, and reach its statekey with index, or pass the data to its corresponding function.